# Animation libraries like Splitting.js and anime.js not working on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, anime.js, splitting.js

Okay I have tried 2 animations libraries, first, [splitting.js](https://splitting.js.org/) and second [anime.js](https://animejs.com/), both work fine on vanilla js but fail on react js, any ideas why? errors don't make sense. Please try the basic npm installation of both the packages and try using them inside a react js project, both of them won't work. Any reasons why? and how to actually use these libraries inside react js? I am guessing its something to do with React's ReactDOM changing the DOM elements and therefore removing the elements needed even before the animation libraries can find them.

**TO RECREATE MY SCENARIO:**
Please try running a simple react js project and try adding both these animation libraries one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many DOM manipulative libraries don't work out of the box with react that has its own way of doing things. You might play around by executing those library code in effect hooks, not in the component declarations itself.

My take would be to use [`react-spring`](https://www.react-spring.io/) which is built from ground up with React in mind. On the other hand, react-anime is just a wrapper around anime.js which shapes it into react's lifecycle.

Comment: bounty given for introducing a better solution that does the job of both the animation libraries with least amount of boilerplate code

Comment: Appreciate it @AKC

Answer (score 0):

To use  anime.js in your react app you might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-anime

Comment: upvote for good answer, somehow I missed this, any ideas on how to use splitting.js ?

Comment: I couldn't find a package that does that, and I personally haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

When using anime.js on a React component you need to make sure to target the DOM element and not the Virtual DOM element. Here's an example. It's a little old, but afaik none of the code/logic is deprecated, and can be easily converted to a functional component using the `useEffect` hook.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { TransitionGroup, Transition } from 'react-transition-group';
import anime from 'animejs';

import './style.scss';

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // create li DOM reference
        this.liRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.animeRef = anime({
            targets: this.liRef.current,
            translateX: () => {
                if( this.props.status == 'entering' ) {
                    return ['-100%', '0%'];
                } else if( this.props.status == 'exiting' ) {
                    return ['0%', '100%'];
                }
            },
            elasticity: () => {
                if( this.props.status == 'entering' ) {
                    return 300;
                } else if( this.props.status == 'exiting' ) {
                    return 0;
                }
            },
            duration: 500
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="list-item" ref={ this.liRef }>
                Hey, I am item number <b>{ this.props.num }</b>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: [1,2,3]
        };
    }

    add() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            data: this.state.data.concat([ this.state.data.length + 1 ])
        });
    }

    remove() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            data: this.state.data.slice(0, -1)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-container">
                <div className="buttons">
                    <button onClick={ this.add.bind(this) }>Add one</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.remove.bind(this) }>Remove one</button>
                </div>

                <TransitionGroup 
                component="ul"
                className="list"
                >
                    {
                        this.state.data.map( num => (
                            <Transition 
                            key={ num }
                            timeout={ 500 }
                            mountOnEnter
                            unmountOnExit
                            >
                                {
                                    ( status ) => {
                                        return <ListItem status={ status } num={ num }/>;
                                    }
                                }
                            </Transition>
                        ) )
                    }
                </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The example came from [this](https://medium.com/jspoint/anime-js-react-transition-group-5f6d0055a3a0) article if you would like more info on the matter.

Here's the [style.scss](https://gist.github.com/thatisuday/039d5e3f360766e9e58e52b3cb697e33#file-rtg-1-style-scss) if you just want to slap in a codesandbox